# Exclude a user by their user ID

Tags: php, mysql

This is the code im using for a leaderboard but it's showing admin users which i would like to remove

here is the code i have tried

```
<?
$j = 0;
foreach($tops as $top){
    $j++;
    $user = $db->QueryFetchArray("SELECT id,login,email,country,coins FROM `users` WHERE `id`='".$top['uid']."'");
      if (!in_array($user->user_id, $excluded_users))
    {
        $excluded_id = array(1);
        //...
    }
?>
```

The user id im trying to remove is `1`

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: and how do you get that array ? i mean array(1). you mean to import that queryfetch array  by declairing array(1) ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `NOT` approach, like this:

```
SELECT id,login,email,country,coins 
FROM `users` 
WHERE `id`='".$top['uid']."'
AND `id` <> 1
```

Reference: [Comparison Functions and Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal).

Comment: Thx but the country and position still shows for the user of the ID of 1

Comment: Then it's something else in your code. This query shows information for all users but user 1.

Answer (score 2):

use this query

```
SELECT id,login,email,country,coins FROM `users` WHERE `id`='".$top['uid']."' and `id` <>'1'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$j = 0;
$excluded_users = array(1);
foreach($tops as $top) {
    if( in_array($top['uid'], $excluded_users ) {
        continue;
    }

    $j++;
    $user = $db->QueryFetchArray("SELECT id,login,email,country,coins FROM `users` WHERE `id`='".$top['uid']."'");

    //...
}
?>
```

[`continue`](http://php.net/continue) lets you skip to the next iteration in the loop.